# How to call a JavaScript function form a p:poll iteration

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have PrimeFaces poll interval to update table in one minute it is disabling a radio button.

```html
<p:poll interval="60" update="sendServer" />
```

`sendServer` is the id of the table, but for the radio button selection I have a script to call while reloading the page.

```js
function loadPageScripts() {
    selectFirstRow(window.document.forms["send-blacklist-form"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all PrimeFaces components triggering Ajax calls, you have the `onstart`, `oncomplete`, `onsuccess` and `onerror` attributes you can use for that.

See:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/poll